# Finding limit from a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, population-dynamics

So to define a new population growth model, this is the (Cauchy problem for a) differential equation of growth I am considering:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}N}{\mathrm{d}t} = rN(t) - r\dfrac{N^2(t)}{kt + b} \\ N(0) = N_0, 
\end{cases}
$$
where $k<0$, $b>0$ are two constant parameters.
From this, I need to find:
$$
\lim_{{t \to -\frac{b}{k}}}{N'(t)}
$$
Until now, I have tried to use L'Hopital's Rule and also explored ways to break down the limit into different compositions.

Can I get some help?

Comment: Any other assumptions like the value of $N(-\frac bk)$?

Comment: Do you have initial conditions, or a range for -b/k

Comment: N(0) = 0, k<0, b>0

Comment: You are right, please refer to the modifications.

Comment: Do not delete your question after getting an answer.  This is rude to the person or people who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find value in the question and answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the most elegant method, but one can compute the limit by first solving the ODE. To simplify it, let's define the variables
$$
n=-\frac{r}{k}N, \qquad s=\frac{r}{k}(kt+b), \tag{1}
$$
in terms of which one can rewrite the ODE as
$$
\frac{dn}{ds}=n+\frac{n^2}{s}. \tag{2}
$$
That's a [Bernoulli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation); one can transform it into a linear ODE with the substitution $u=\frac{1}{n}$:
$$
n'=-\frac{u'}{u^2}=\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{su^2} \implies u'+u=-\frac{1}{s}. \tag{3}
$$
Multiplying $(3)$ by $e^{s}$ and integrating yields
$$
e^{s}(u'+u)=(e^su)'=-\frac{e^s}{s}\implies u=e^{-s}(C-\text{Ei}(s)), \tag{4}
$$
where $\text{Ei}(s)=\int_{-\infty}^s\frac{e^x}{x}dx$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). Finally,
$$
n(s)=\frac{1}{u}=\frac{e^s}{C-\text{Ei(s)}}. \tag{5}
$$
Now we are ready to compute $\lim_{t\to-b/k}N'(t)$. From $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows that
$$
\lim_{t\to-b/k}N'(t)=-k\lim_{s\to 0^-}\frac{dn}{ds}=-k\lim_{s\to 0^-} \left(n(s)+\frac{n^2(s)}{s}\right). \tag{6}
$$
Since $\text{Ei}(s)= \gamma+\ln(-s)+O(s)$ for $0<-s\ll 1$, it follows from $(5)$ that $\lim_{s\to 0^-}n(s)=0$ and
$$
\lim_{s\to 0^-}\frac{n^2(s)}{s}=\lim_{s\to 0^-}\frac{1}{s(\ln(-s))^2}=-\infty. \tag{7}
$$
Since $k<0$, it follows from $(6)$ and $(7)$ that
$$
\lim_{t\to-b/k}N'(t)=-\infty. \tag{8}
$$

Comment: Sorry, could you cite a source for the approximation you made for the exponential integral?

Comment: The article in Wikipedia linked in my answer, or formula 8.214.1 of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's [Table of Integrals, Series, and Products](http://fisica.ciens.ucv.ve/~svincenz/TISPISGIMR.pdf).